# Error during Kali Linux Android install

Tags: installation, android, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali on a Samsung Tab S with Linux Deploy and during install it threw up the following error:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Can anyone tell me how to get it working?

Edit : Sorry about the low quality picture. Console Output posted below

```
[9:12:09] dbus ... done 
[09:12:09] xorg ... done 
[09:12:09] packages ... done 
[09:12:09] Installing additional packages:  
[09:12:09] Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
[09:12:09]   Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
[09:12:09] Reading package lists...
[09:12:18] W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'
[09:12:18] W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
[09:12:18] Reading package lists...
[09:12:18] Building dependency tree...
[09:12:19] The following additional packages will be installed:
[09:12:19]   checkpolicy dh-python fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libdrm2 libedit2
[09:12:19]   libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libgl1-mesa-glx
[09:12:19]   libglapi-mesa libgssapi-krb5-2 libice6 libjpeg62-turbo libk5crypto3
[09:12:19]   libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libmpdec2 libperl5.22 libpng16-16
[09:12:19]   libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libsm6
[09:12:19]   libsqlite3-0 libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxaw7
[09:12:19]   libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0
[09:12:19]   libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb1
[09:12:19]   libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6
[09:12:19]   libxinerama1 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1
[09:12:19]   libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 mime-support openssh-client
[09:12:19]   openssh-sftp-server perl perl-modules-5.22 policycoreutils python3
[09:12:19]   python3-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal selinux-utils ucf x11-common
[09:12:19]   x11-utils xauth
[09:12:19] Suggested packages:
[09:12:19]   libdpkg-perl krb5-doc krb5-user ssh-askpass libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere
[09:12:19]   rssh molly-guard ufw perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
[09:12:19]   | libterm-readline-perl-perl make python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
[09:12:19]   python3.5-venv python3.5-doc binutils binfmt-support logcheck syslog-summary
[09:12:19]   tightvnc-java mesa-utils
[09:12:19] Recommended packages:
[09:12:19]   libgl1-mesa-dri krb5-locales tcpd bzip2 file xz-utils ncurses-term rename
[09:12:19]   policycoreutils-python-utils selinux-policy-default setools xfonts-base
[09:12:19]   x11-xserver-utils
[09:12:19] The following NEW packages will be installed:
[09:12:19]   checkpolicy dh-python fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libdrm2 libedit2
[09:12:19]   libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfreetype6 libgl1-mesa-glx
[09:12:19]   libglapi-mesa libgssapi-krb5-2 libice6 libjpeg62-turbo libk5crypto3
[09:12:19]   libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libmpdec2 libperl5.22 libpng16-16
[09:12:19]   libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libsm6
[09:12:19]   libsqlite3-0 libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxaw7
[09:12:19]   libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0
[09:12:19]   libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb1
[09:12:19]   libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6
[09:12:19]   libxinerama1 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1
[09:12:19]   libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 mime-support openssh-client
[09:12:19]   openssh-server openssh-sftp-server perl perl-modules-5.22 policycoreutils
[09:12:19]   python3 python3-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal selinux-basics
[09:12:19]   selinux-utils tightvncserver ucf x11-common x11-utils xauth
[09:12:20] 0 upgraded, 80 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[09:12:20] Need to get 19.3 MB of archives.
[09:12:20] After this operation, 78.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
[09:12:20] WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
[09:12:20]   libwrap0 perl-modules-5.22 libperl5.22 perl x11-common libice6 libsm6
[09:12:20]   libxau6 libxdmcp6 libxcb1 libx11-data libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1
[09:12:20]   libxfixes3 libxdamage1 libxext6 libexpat1 libpng16-16 libfreetype6 ucf
[09:12:20]   fonts-dejavu-core fontconfig-config libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxft2
[09:12:20]   libxinerama1 libxpm4 libxshmfence1 libxi6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1
[09:12:20]   libxxf86vm1 libpython3.5-minimal python3.5-minimal python3-minimal
[09:12:20]   mime-support libmpdec2 libsqlite3-0 libpython3.5-stdlib python3.5
[09:12:20]   libpython3-stdlib dh-python python3 libedit2 libkeyutils1 libkrb5support0
[09:12:20]   libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 openssh-client checkpolicy libdrm2
[09:12:20]   libfontenc1 libglapi-mesa libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0
[09:12:20]   libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1
[09:12:20]   libxcb-xfixes0 libgl1-mesa-glx libjpeg62-turbo libxt6 libxmu6 libxaw7
[09:12:20]   libxmuu1 libxrandr2 openssh-sftp-server openssh-server selinux-utils
[09:12:20]   policycoreutils selinux-basics x11-utils xauth tightvncserver
[09:12:20] E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
[09:12:20] <<< end: configure 
[09:12:58] Updating configuration file ... done
```

Comment: the screenshots are unreadable.  either make them bigger or type in the errors.

Comment: Sorry about that, Console output posted